# Typescript/lodash: how to get results/objects with multiple common properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, filter, group-by, lodash

I am looking for a lodash/typerscript solution for a groupBy function with multiple properties.
Here's what I have tried so far:

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "jobId": 1001,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1001,
        "id": 2,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1002,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1002,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 2,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 2,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 2,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 2,
        "balance": 100
    }
]
```

Typescript code:

```
  // Group of same ids
  let mergeResults = _.groupBy(this.BSSDealresults, function (n) {
     return n.timeSegmentId;
  });
  const objKeys = Object.keys(mergeResults);
  const AggregateResults = [];
  objKeys.forEach(item => {
    if (mergeResults[item].length > 1) {

      let agg_balance = 0;

      mergeResults[item].forEach(element => {
        agg_balance += element.balance;
      });
      AggregateResults.push({
        id: mergeResults[item][0].id,
        jobId: mergeResults[item][0].jobId,
        balance: agg_balance
      });
    } else {
      AggregateResults.push(mergeResults[item][0]);
    }
  })
```

This solution is giving aggragation of balance grouped by only same "id" as I have applied a lodash "_groupBy" funtion based on a property "id".

Whereas I am looking for aggregate results based on multiple properties e.g. id, jobId and timeSegId.

Is there any way in lodash/typescript where we can apply grouby using multiple properties?

The expected output should be:

```
[
    {
        "jobId": 1001,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1001,
        "id": 2,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1002,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 200
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 1,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 2,
        "balance": 100
    },
    {
        "jobId": 1003,
        "id": 1,
        "timeSegmentId": 2,
        "balance": 300
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you're hoping for, given your input array? (in an edit to your question)

Comment: What do you want to result? Show me a example.

Comment: Updated my question with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a key for `_.groupBy()` by creating a string out of the 3 ids. Then you can [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map) the groups `BSSDealresults` object, clone the 1st element using [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) (or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), and get the combined balance with [`_.sumBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sumBy):

```js
const BSSDealresults = [{"jobId":1001,"id":1,"timeSegmentId":1,"balance":100},{"jobId":1001,"id":2,"timeSegmentId":1,"balance":100},{"jobId":1002,"id":1,"timeSegmentId":1,"balance":100},{"jobId":1002,"id":1,"timeSegmentId":1,"balance":100},{"jobId":1003,"id":1,"timeSegmentId":1,"balance":100},{"jobId":1003,"id":1,"timeSegmentId":2,"balance":100}];

const mergeResults = _.groupBy(BSSDealresults, ({ id, jobId, timeSegmentId }) => `${id}-${jobId}-${timeSegmentId}`);

const AggregateResults = _.map(mergeResults, group => ({
  ...group[0],
  balance: _.sumBy(group, 'balance')
}));

console.log(AggregateResults);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```